# Utility for graph manipulation in java

Tags: java, collections, graph, dictionary, treemap

I needed a graph structure of `key ==>> value` such as following image:

[image]

Numbers in circle are key of  its node.

I wanted access to stored value in key `2-7-6-5` and I wanted by `2-7` key retrieve a sub-graph contains collectin of `2`, `6-5`, `6-11` keys-values , so I wrote my implementation by nested maps and it worked fine but my question is :

Is there any custom `Map` implementation or third-party library for solve my situation for cleanup my code from  manipulation manually such as `String.split` or loop and condition statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really just looking for a 3rd-Party Java Library to work with graphs take a look at [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) it has plenty of features for graph manipulation. However, it might be overkill for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

take this one - really good for graph manipulations, and also for dispaying graph structure in swing

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jgraph</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgraph</artifactId>
    <version>5.13.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

http://www.jgraph.com

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly simple graph construction and traversal problem. You do not need any libraries. You can do it in a simple java class. For e.g.

http://it-essence.xs4all.nl/roller/technology/entry/three_tree_traversals_in_java

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd want to implement nodes as class instances and links as references. Using maps to implement graph edges would be quite complicated and inefficient.  Little wonder you'd want to clean up your code. I'm not sure I understand your problem perfectly, but this ought to be close:

```
// Null nodes are the simplest type. They represent missing children.
class NullNode {

    // Get the values of all leaves descended from this node as a set.
    Set<Integer> getValues() { return new HashSet(0); }

    // Get the values descended from the node at the end of the given
    // key path as a set.  For a null node, this should not be called.
    Set<Integer> getValues(int [] path, int i) { raise new IllegalOperationException(); }

    // Initiate the search for values.  The only way that's okay
    // for null nodes is when the path is empty.
    Set<Integer> getValues(int [] path) {
        if (path.length == 0)
            return new HashSet(0);
        else
            raise new IllegalOperationException();
    }
}

// A regular node is a null node with a key. It should
// never be instantiated. Use Interior or Leaf nodes for that.
abstract class Node extends NullNode {

    int key;

    // Initiate the search for values.  Only descend if the key matches.
    Set<Integer> getValues(int [] path) {
        return (path.length > 0 && path[0] == key) ? getValues(path, 1) : new HashSet(0);
    }
}

// Interior nodes have two children, which may be Null, Interior, or Leaf.
class InteriorNode extends Node {

    Node left, right;

    Set<Integer> getValues() {
        Set<Integer> v = left.getValues();
        v.addAll(right.getValues());
        return v;
    }

    Set<Integer> getValues(int [] path, int i) {
        if (i + 1 < path.length) {
            // Again we only descend if the key matches.
            if (path[i + 1] == left.key)  return getValues(left, i + 1);
            if (path[i + 1] == right.key) return getValues(right, i + 1);
            return new HashSet(0);
        }
        return getValues(); // Get values from both children.
    }
}

// A leaf node has no children and a value.
class LeafNode extends Node {

    int value;

    Set<Integer> getValues() {
        HashSet<Integer> v = new HashSet(1);
        v.add(value);
        return v;
    }

    Set<Integer> getValues(int [] path, int i) {
        return (i + 1 >= path.length) ? getValues() : new HashSet(0);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The best graph library which I have found is not written in Java but in Scala and makes usage of some powerful scala features not available in Java, such as abstract types.

It is called Graph for Scala and it is extremely comprehensive, but I have to warn you that while Scala and Java they are intercompatible (you can build them in the same project and call a Java class from a Scala class and vice-versa), some problems might rise when calling Scala from Java when it comes to some features which are not available in Java.

http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-graph/wiki

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted in `Java`.

Comment: I won't spend time trying to explain why if you have an existing project written in Java you might want to continue the project in Scala, but tell me that's it..

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any custom `Map` implementation or third-party library for solve my situation for cleanup my code from manipulation manually such as `String.split` or loop and condition statements?

If you want to remove the freedom to written manipulate code then you can create your own libraries. You can easily create libraries in Eclipse by exporting your classes into a Jar file, which I would presume is a trivial task in NetBeans.

If you want to protect against changes to the graph after construction then you need to create an immutable data structure. With an immutable graph structure you have to view the Graph as a Universe, and each operation is a GraphOperation. You can never modify a Graph, only create a new Graph that results from crossing the Graph with your list of GraphOperations. Presuming your Graph structure holds unique node values, this will not pose too much of a problem, since you can happily describe relations using values. Your code will look something like this:

```
Graph graph2 = graph1.process(graph1.GetTopNode().RemoveLeft());
graph2 = graph2.process(graph2.GetNode(7).AddRight(8));
```

`GetTopNode()` returns an object that only provides a view of the nodes. `RemoveLeft()` returns a `GraphOperation` object, which `Graph.process()` uses to create a new graph from the operation. If you want, it could just return a `Graph` implementation that internally stores a link to `graph1`, and the list of `GraphOperation` instances that have been passed into it, allowing you to avoid copying the graph structures too often (pretty much like a string buffer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Graph database and manipulation in Java, [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/resources/) might help you. This can be more than what you have bargained for if you are looking for a perfect Graph DB and manipulation API.

It gives you very advanced options to traverse the graph nodes, relationships, auditing. Neo4j is being used across organizations to store very complex hierarchical data, the performance by Neo4j is far better than oracle based R-DB's for complex hierarchical databases.